# JTable resizes according to ScrollPane's size

Tags: java, jtable, scrollpane

I am trying to make the JTable adjust its size automatically as I resize the window containing the JTable.

As the Example below:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/SimpleTableDemoProject/src/components/SimpleTableDemo.java

The JTable will adjust its width, also it has a scroll bar on the right if the height is too small to display all.

This one is the JFrame, I use separate class extends JPanel:

```
public class GUIFrame 
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    //Setting up JFrame's basic properties
    JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Muney Manager");
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Setting up panels:
    JPanel mPanel = new JPanel();
    mPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mPanel,BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

    TablePanel tPanel = new TablePanel();
    ToolBar buttonPanel = new ToolBar(tPanel);

    mPanel.add(buttonPanel);
    mPanel.add(tPanel);

    //Setting up Panels and Frame to be displayed :3
    mainFrame.getContentPane().add(mPanel);
    mainFrame.pack();
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);

}
```

This is the one containing the JTable:

```
public class TablePanel extends JPanel
{

//DefaultTableModel is needed for adding new rows
private JTable table;
private DefaultTableModel tmodel;

private JScrollPane scrollPane;

//Table's column name
private String[] columnNames = {"Date",
                                "Category",
                                "Details",
                                "Add/Subtract",
                                "Total"};


Object[][] data = {
        {20140925, "Grocery", "Supermarket", -5.23,600.00},
        {20141013,"Car Maintenance", "Changing Tires", -200.00, 400.00}
};




public TablePanel()
{

    //Initializing tmodel and putting it into table
    //It's needed for "adding rows" method
    tmodel = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
    table = new JTable();

    table.setModel(tmodel);


    //Setting up JScrollPane, table Headder
    //and make scrollPane visible 
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    add(new JScrollPane(table));

}
```

For some reason, I can't get it work, what's wrong with my code?
The JTable width doesn't resize, also I can't seem to get a Scroll Bar on the right

[image]

Comment: Why not use a `BorderLayout` instead of a `BoxLayout`?

Comment: I thought that BoxLayout will be simpler in terms of my goal for the program.  Does using BorderLayout solve the problem?

Comment: `BorderLayout` will cause the component in the `CENTER` position to occupy the entire contents of the available space of the container.  The `NORTH` component will be expanded to fill the horizontal space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a `BorderLayout` instead...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Muney Manager");
            mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            //Setting up panels:
            JPanel mPanel = new JPanel();
            mPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            TablePanel tPanel = new TablePanel();
            ToolBar buttonPanel = new ToolBar(tPanel);

            mPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            mPanel.add(tPanel);

            //Setting up Panels and Frame to be displayed :3
            mainFrame.getContentPane().add(mPanel);
            mainFrame.pack();
            mainFrame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Or if you want more control, maybe even a `GridBagLayout`

**Updated**

`JPanel` by default uses a `FlowLayout`, try changing the `TablePanel` to use a `BorderLayout` as well...

```
public TablePanel()
{
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    //Initializing tmodel and putting it into table
    //It's needed for "adding rows" method
    tmodel = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
    table = new JTable();

    table.setModel(tmodel);


    //Setting up JScrollPane, table Headder
    //and make scrollPane visible 
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    add(new JScrollPane(table));

}
```

Comment: I just tried the new codes that you post it, somehow it doesn't work and no changes at all.  One thing I found out though, if I directly add the tPanel into mainFrame:   mainFrame.getContentPane().add(tPanel);   The JTable in TablePanel still doesn't change and resize, I believe that it has someting to do with TablePanel rather than Layout Manager.